# C# PDF table add row in wrong position

Tags: c#, winforms, itext, windows-forms-designer, itext7

[EDIT due to misunderstanding of the answer]

I'm doing a simple program in C# with PDF file creation with iText7.
In this PDF i'm adding a table whose first cell starts at a certain position in the file.

I don't know if I set the position correctly, but everytime I add another cell with `tab.StartNewRow()` the resulting new table is repositioned taking THAT last cell as position reference, putting the previously added cells **from that point up**, while I want to add the cells **from that point down.**

Which method should I use? That's my code:
Previously I set the position of the first table cell using `tab1.SetFixedPosition(20, heigh, width);`

and then, in order to add the other cells:

```
if (mylistbox.Items.Count > 0)
  {
     tab1.AddCell("FIRST CELL");
     tab1.StartNewRow();
     for (int i = 0; i < mylistbox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
          tab1.AddCell(mylistbox.Items[i].ToString());
          tab1.StartNewRow();
        }
        doc.Add(tab1);
  }
```

[EDIT #2] in order to explain my issue better

I have to put 5 tables, which have to grow from a certain point DOWN, positioned at equal distances, same height and width in the doc. This image explains how it should result:

[image: pdfExample]

Comment: That's indeed what `SetFixedPosition` does, it's documented as *The coordinates specified correspond to the bottom-left corner of the element and it grows upwards.*

Comment: so.... do you know a method which takes as reference the top of the table and makes it grow downwards?

Comment: false, it doesn't work. It puts the next table under the previous one because it calculates the position relative to the previous item

Comment: Have you considered creating a `Canvas` on the page in question with left, top, and right margins as you want them, and the bottom far enough down to allow any expected table size, and then adding the table without `SetFixedPosition` to that `Canvas`?

Comment: You mean creating a different canvas for every single table and then adding it to the doc with different positions? So, for example, if I have  5 tables, I have to use 5 canvas?

Comment: *"You mean ..."* - yes. It sounds a bit tedious but actually isn't that bad, two or three lines in code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to be tedious, I'll try it out! Thanks! ;)

Comment: *"I didn't want to be tedious"* - no, no, i didn't mean you, i meant the procedure i proposed.

Comment: If you're interested, I put a draw to explain better what I mean @mkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a WPF application, I have a `ListBox` with 5 items, numbered 1 through 5. This should be very similar to WinForms.

The `CreatePercentArray` takes a size which is equal to the amount of columns in a row.

An interesting article about tables: [link](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/101-a-very-simple-table)

```
  private void CreateListBoxTable(Document pdfDoc)
        {
            // Create an array where each item has an equal width, and use the entire pdf width
            // The CreatePercentArray takes a size which is equal to the amount of columns in a row
            // By using percentages, they will automatically adapt
            // Use CreatePointArray for exacter measurements
            var table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(2)).UseAllAvailableWidth();

            if (!MyListBox.Items.IsEmpty)
            {
                foreach (var listBoxItem in MyListBox.Items)
                {
                    table.AddCell(((ListBoxItem) listBoxItem).Content.ToString());
                }
            }
            // Adds table to document
            pdfDoc.Add(table);
            // Closes document
            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I explained my issue badly, it's my fault, I'm not sure if you have understood my question. Anyway, I'll try out your method, if you may read my question again, I'll be very glad.
 Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hello, I tried using your exact code without the `SetFixedPosition`and using a table with just 1 column. Adding the items your way even when the program is running does not affect the position of my table, it just adds items vertically and downwards. The first items added on top and the last items on the bottom. I still don't see what your exact problem is and how it is occurring.

Comment: Doing this way, of course it works, but I want to put the tables at a certain positions in the document. So without using SetFixedPosition the problem is solved, but the table is positioned randomly

Comment: I need a method to put the first cell of the table at a customed position, and at the same time make it grow downwards

Comment: Hello, I edited my question improving my issue explaination and putting a draw to explain better how it should result, thanks for your patience @Mayfair